# How to save number of functiton inserted in class callings in Python?

Tags: python, function, class

How to save number of functiton `needed_function` callings?
And its called by functions as `many_functions_that_calling_needed_function1` etc.
I have following class schema:

```
class MyClass
    def __init__
...
    def my_function
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def needed_function
        if first_statement:
            """Count number of calling if statement"""
        elif second statement:
            """Count number of calling elif statement"""

    def many_functions_that_calling_needed_function1
        self.needed_function()

    def many_functions_that_calling_needed_function2
        self.needed_function()

    def many_functions_that_calling_needed_function3
        self.needed_function()

    def many_functions_that_calling_needed_function4
        self.needed_function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to keep track of how many times a function inside a class (a method) is called, you can do it like this:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.calls=0

    def needed_function(self):
        """if this function gets called, increase the value of self.calls by 1"""
        self.calls+=1
        # add whatever else you want here

c=TestClass()
print(c.calls)    # prints 0 cause needed_function hasn't been called yet
c.needed_function()    # needed_function is called here
print(c.calls)     # prints 1
c.needed_function()    # called again
print(c.calls)    # prints 2
```